# Is it possible to disaggregate data using a system of equations?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have several data series with date ranges and averages, but I don't have the actual value for each day and I'm wondering if you can back into the actual values using a system of equations.

Here is my example. I want to find out the values for each day, something like this:

| Date | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Jan 1 | 3 |
| Jan 2 | 4 |
| Jan 3 | 5 |
| Jan 4 | 6 |
| Jan 5 | 7 |

However, the only data I have is the following:

| Date Range | Average |
| --- | --- |
| Jan 1-2 | 3.5 |
| Jan 2-3 | 4.5 |
| Jan 3-4 | 5.5 |
| Jan 4-5 | 6.5 |

I also have this table:
| Date Range | Average |
| ---------- | ----- |
| Jan 1-3 | 4 |
| Jan 2-4 | 5 |
| Jan 3-5 | 6 |

And this table:
| Date Range | Average |
| ---------- | ----- |
| Jan 1-4 | 4.5 |
| Jan 2-5 | 5.5 |

And this table:
| Date Range | Average |
| ---------- | ----- |
| Jan 1-5 | 5 |

What I don't have is any data where I have an average of non-consecutive days. For instance:
| Dates | Average |
| ---------- | ----- |
| Jan 1 & Jan 3 | 4 |
| Jan 2 & Jan 4 | 5 |

So when I assign a variable for each day, I get a system of equations that looks like this:

| Date | Variable |
| --- | --- |
| Jan 1 | a |
| Jan 2 | b |
| Jan 3 | c |
| Jan 4 | d |
| Jan 5 | e |

- (a+b)/2 = 3.5
- (b+c)/2 = 4.5
- (c+d)/2 = 5.5
- (d+e)/2 = 6.5
- (a+b+c)/3 = 4
- etc.

If I could get an aggregation for non-consecutive days I could solve this pretty easily because I would have something like this:

- (a+b)/2 = 3.5
- (b+c)/2 = 4.5
- (c+a)/2 = 4

But I can't and I'm not sure how to solve this system of equations. Is this even possible?

Comment: Since these equations are first-degree (linear) systems, a quick analysis looks at the number of unknowns vs. the number of equations.  It's impossible to "disaggregate" if the number of unknowns is greater than the number of equations, for example if there are just two days, $a,b$.  Then your only equation is the one for averaging $a$ and $b$.

Comment: You have 5 unknowns but only 4 independent linear equations. You can solve everything in terms of the unknown Jan 1 value, but one more constraint would be needed to solve completely.

Comment: @A.Webb:  Actually there are enough independent linear equations to solve for five unknowns, since in addition to the pairs of adjacent days, the total range average is available.

Comment: Right, missed the misformatted info. Only the first
table plus one additional piece, e.g. row 1 of table 2, is needed. From 1.1 and 1.2, $a + 2b + c = 16$ and from 2.1, $a + b + c = 12$, so $b = 4$. The rest can then be recovered from table 1.

Comment: @A.Webb: If you want to put together a nicely formatted Answer, I'll be happy to promise an upvote.

Comment: @A.Webb thank you so much for your help! This is my first post ever here and you have been super helpful!

Comment: Also, not sure why it's mis-formatting those tables, when I edit this post they look just fine, but as soon as I save, it mis-formats them again...